# How do you call the function call operator on a unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11

If a class has a function call operator that returns a reference to a container (heavily redacted):

```
class client_connection { 
public:
    concurrent_queue<T>& operator()() { return client; }
    concurrent_queue<T> client;
};
```

And another class which has a member of `client_connection`:

```
class remote {
public:
    void get_version() {
        auto d = ... something to generate data ...
        client().push(d.begin(), d.end());
    }
...
client_connection client;
};
```

This works if `client` is constructed as part of the `remote` object.  However if you pass ownership to `remote` via a `unique_ptr` how do you call the function call operator?

Upon changing the call to `client()->push(d.begin(), d.end());` the resulting error message suggests that the issue is because the push is on the `unique_ptr`, not the `client_connection`.

Using `.get()` is now working on the underlying object but without function call operator: `client.get()->push(m.begin(), m.end()); // error: ‘class client_connection<unsigned char>’ has no member named ‘push’`

However trying various combinations to invoke the function call operator all fail.  How do you call the function call operator on an object contained in a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In general you have to use unique_ptr->operator()(args...).

Comment: @Barry How can I provide a complete example when I am asking how to call something? Also screens of unrelated classes will result in the reader trying to work out where the issue is.

Comment: @graham.reeds Easily? Just provide an minimal example that doesn't work. And obviously don't include the "screens of unrelated classes"...

Comment: I've always wished I could use `client->()` in such situations.  Alas, such syntax is not valid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do it like this

```
client->operator()().push(m.begin(), m.end());
```

You need to actually call the operator because you have a pointer. Alternatively, dereference the unique pointer instead:

```
(*client)().push(m.begin(), m.end());
```